# How to select comment count, Sum of votes, and whether active user has voted

Tags: mysql, count, sum, left-join

Im having trouble structuring my MySQL query to return an accurate comment count, sum of votes, and the active users vote.

My tables are

```
wall_posts ( id, message, username, etc )
comments   ( id, wall_id, username, text, etc )
votes      ( id, wall_id, vote (+1 or -1), username )
```

My query looks like this

```
SELECT
    wall_posts.*,
    COUNT( comments.wall_id ) AS comment_count,
    COALESCE( SUM( v1.vote ), 0 ) AS vote_tally,
    v2.vote 
FROM
    wall_posts 
    LEFT JOIN comments ON wall_posts.id = comments.wall_id 
    LEFT JOIN votes v1 ON wall_posts.id = v1.wall_id 
    LEFT JOIN votes v2 ON wall_posts.id = v2.wall_id AND v2.username=:username 
WHERE
    symbol =: symbol
GROUP BY
    wall_posts.id
ORDER BY
    date DESC
LIMIT 15
```

It works for always returning the correct value for the specific active users vote (+1 or -1) or null if hasnt voted. If there are no comments on an item, the total vote sum is correct. If there are any comments, the vote sum will always be equal to the comment count, possibly with a negative sign if there are down votes but always equal to the amount of comments.

I think its obviously the way ive connected my tables but i just cant figure out why its copying the comment count, 1000000 points to someone who can explain this to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the aggregate operations in subqueries. Right now instead you're `JOIN`ing all of the tables (pre-aggregation) together. If you remove the aggregates (and the `GROUP BY`) you'll see the large mass of data which doesn't really mean anything.

Instead, try this (note I'm using a `VIEW`):

```
CREATE VIEW walls_posts_stats AS

SELECT
    wall_posts.id,
    COALESCE( comments_stats.comment_count, 0 ) AS comment_count,
    COALESCE( votes_stats.vote_tally, 0 ) AS vote_tally
FROM

    wall_posts

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            wall_id,
            COUNT(*) AS comment_count
        FROM
            comments
        GROUP BY
            wall_id
    ) AS comments_stats ON wall_posts.id = comments_stats.wall_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            wall_id,
            SUM( vote ) AS vote_tally
        FROM
            votes
        GROUP BY
            wall_id
    ) AS votes_stats ON wall_posts.id = votes_stats.wall_id
```

Then you can query it JOINed with your original wall data:

```
SELECT
    wall_posts.*, -- note: avoid the use of * in production queries
    stats.comment_count,
    stats.vote_tally,
    user_votes.vote
FROM
    wall_posts
    INNER JOIN walls_posts_stats AS stats ON wall_posts.id = stats.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            wall_id,
            vote
        FROM
            votes
        WHERE
            username = :username
    ) AS user_votes ON wall_posts.id = user_votes.wall_id
ORDER BY
    date DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Hypothetically you could combine it into a single large query (basically copy+paste the VIEW body into the `INNER JOIN walls_posts_stats` clause) but I feel that would introduce maintainability issues.

While MySQL does support views, it does not support parameterized views (aka composable table-valued functions; stored procedures are not composable) so that's why the `user_votes` subquery isn't in the `walls_posts_stats` VIEW.

Comment: Hi Dai, thanks for the reply. Its looks a bit more complicated than what i had in mind! (Mainly because ive never heard about views, i will read up on them now. Would you say its impossible to do it in one query almost like how i had it, without views. Or is it impossible to aggregate, count, and join all of this in one statement